# Vimwiki: My vimwiki index file was deleted by accident. Is there a way to recreate it?

Tags: gvim

My vimwiki index file was deleted by accident. Is there a way to recreate it? I have all the *.wiki files that have the content.

I was hoping there was a command to generate an index from capturing all the *.wiki file names.

Comment: This sounds like it would be better addressed at the vimwiki maintainers, who may or may not be around here

Comment: I went throught the vimwiki docs again and didn't see a exsiting way to do it. However it can be done with a macro as long ad the .wiki files haven't been deleted/lost. Fortunately all my *.wiki files were available. I just copied the file names and put them all in a index.wiki file under the appropriate wiki file directory in my Dropbox folder. It worked for a one time fix.

Comment: If you're referring to https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki, then based on the doc the index is just a wiki file that you maintain. A simple solution might be something like `:read !find ~/mywiki/ -name '*.wiki' | sed -e 's/^/[[/' -e 's/$/]]/'`. AFAICT there is no standard index format or function/command to build an index, since it's whatever content you want there to be.

Comment: That's a very compact and elegant answer. Thanks.